# OnClick Replacing View in RecyclerView with a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to replace a master view with a detail fragment once the view has been clicked within its `RecyclerView`.
The problem is that when the view is clicked, the fragment inserts itself usually above or below the view that was clicked. Ideally, the green fragment seen in the attached image would replace the view with its corresponding date.

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIbgq.jpg)

I've tried making this work in ListView instead of RecyclerView, but the result is exactly the same.

Here's a look at the `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.nameView.setText(shows.get(position).getName());
        holder.staffView.setText(shows.get(position).getWorkSchedule());
        holder.dateView.setText(shows.get(position).getDate());
        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.linearLayout.setTag((int)position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return shows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int eventId = shows.get((int) v.getTag()).getEventId();
        String date = shows.get((int) v.getTag()).getDate();

        DetailedEvent fragment = new DetailedEvent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Observable<EventStats> eventStats = dag.apiCaller().fetchOneEventStats(eventId);
        dag.apiCaller().fetchEventSnapshot(eventId).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .zipWith(dag.apiCaller().fetchOneEventStats(eventId), new BiFunction<EventSnapshot, EventStats, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object apply(EventSnapshot eventSnapshot, EventStats eventStats) throws Exception {
                        bundle.putString("sold", (eventSnapshot.getRevenueProducingTickets() + "/" + eventSnapshot.getCapacity()));
                        bundle.putString("description", eventStats.getDescription());
                        bundle.putString("name", eventSnapshot.getName());
                        bundle.putString("date", date);
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        FragmentTransaction fTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction()
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, 0, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                        fTrans.replace(R.id.linear_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.toString()).commit();
                        v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        return bundle;
                    }
                }).subscribe();
    }
```

I know versions of this question have been asked already, but I couldn't find any resource for replacing a view with a fragment, rather than a fragment with a fragment or an activity, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Do you want the detail `Fragment` to replace the whole `RecyclerView`? Or just the one item in the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I'm trying to replace just one item. Which is to say that the fragment should replace the view that has been clicked within the RecyclerView.

In the attached image, the green block is the Fragment, which should take the place of the view with the corresponding date.

Comment: That's not really a recommended usage for `Fragment`s. In a `RecyclerView`, it would be easier to do regular `View` manipulation. Your current problem is that `FragmentManager` is going to use the first `R.id.linear_layout` it finds in the `Activity`'s layout. Since your `RecyclerView` has multiple items, presumably each having an `R.id.linear_layout`, you can't be certain which one it's going to end up using.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point out that I see that you are basically trying to have a different view for items that have been clicked.  I've had the same thought myself.  Are you also doing a progress bar in the list item?

Changing the views themselves kind of breaks the whole idea of having a few views that you can recycle with new information. Doesn't it? (I still want to try it)

Might I suggest having what you want already in all the views and then exposing or hiding it or inserting new info. That seems to be what you are doing with the progress bar? Remember a view with nothing in it shows nothing, but does take up space.

The other thing is, updating a progress bar or doing any animations when the view is recycled is likely to cause you trouble. I like your reasoning that it is your view and you can do with it what you want :) but the recycler view may have another plan.

Comment: I believe I took Mike's advice and just made due with changing the visibility of views nested within the RV item after completing the network call